# RGB Macro c# equivalent

Tags: c#, rgb

Is there an equivalent function in c# for the rgb macro in c++? I am trying to convert a managed c++ file to c#.
Is there a workaround for the getrvalue , getgvalue methods etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RGB macro in C++ takes a byte for each channel as input.

C# has an equivalent function:

```
Color.FromArgb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)
Color.FromArgb(int red, int green int blue)
```

You can specify RGB or RGBA values.

Comment: Are you referencing System.Drawing.dll?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`Color.FromArgb(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx), which does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are storing the RGB data, ie 32-bit, 24-bit, 16-bit,15-bit, 12-bit, etc.

You can usually extract the bit fields with the `>>` and `&` operators, something like

```
int r = ( color >> 16) & 0xFF;
```

but this depends on how color is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Color` structure. Documentation [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as a function in c# since its relatively easy.

```
((ushort)(((byte)(r) | ((ushort)((byte)(g)) << 8)) | (((uint)(byte)(b)) << 16)));
```

Comment: But, Tyler, what about the workarounds for getrvalue and other other such methods?

Comment: Are you talking to yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator` to instantiate a `Color` object, and then access its `R`, `G` and `B` properties respectively.